# How does it work "checking bit flag"

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I've read other questions about this, but they don't answer my question.

In the following code I understand that it checks if that bit is set, but my question is why?

```
bool test(uint8_t& flag)
{
   return flag & (1 << 4);
}
```

I don't get why it returns a `bool` and it works, flag is `uint8_t` and `1 << 4` should be something like this `00010000` (I think). Why does that code return the value of the desired single bit and not the rightmost or something like that?

Comment: Can you pick a language, are you using C or C++? Looks like C++ but I want to make sure.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: seeing the use of the bool keyword, I would assume that C is irrelevant here.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: `#include <stdbool.h>`. the c++ hint is the pass by reference (which, BTW, doesn't make sense here), but apart from that, the answer is identical in both languages.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: That's not to mention the C++ in the title. :)

Comment: Yes, I'm using C++. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `4.12` *Boolean conversions* says (*emphasis mine*):

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. **A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false; any other value is converted to true.** For direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.

So any non-zero value will be converted to `true`.

You expressed some doubts as to the result of `1 << 4` we have a quick way to check this using [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::bitset<8> b1(1<<4);

    std::cout << b1 << std::endl ;

    return 0;
}
```

and we can see the result is indeed `00010000` since [bitwise and](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_AND_.22.26.22) only set a bit to `1` if the bit in both operands are `1` then the result of `flag & (1 << 4)` will only be *non-zero* if bit `5` of `flag` is also `1`.

Comment: I've upvoted before, but mentioning `std::bitset` would deserve at least one more ;) ...

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. That functionality is indeed useful.

Answer (score 3):

An `int` can be converted to a `bool`. If its value is zero, the converted value ist `false`, otherwise it is `true`.
Check it out yorself:

```
bool f = 0;
bool t = 5;
```

> Prvalues of integral, floating-point, unscoped enumeration, pointer, and pointer-to-member types can be converted to prvalues of type bool.
>
> The value zero (for integral, floating-point, and unscoped enumeration) and the null pointer and the null pointer-to-member values become false. All other values become true.

See: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Boolean_conversions)

Comment: note: you will see this used quite heavily, especially in the form of `if (integer)`

Comment: Thank you, even I have used it, but with just `1` (`true`) or `0` (`false`), I didn't know `0` was `false` and everything else is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

The `&` operator performs a bitwise boolean AND operation. That means that a bit is set in the final output if, and only if, it is set in both inputs, so for example

```
  00011100
& 01010101
  --------
= 00010100

  11010101
& 01010101
  --------
= 01010101
```

So, if you use a mask that has only a single bit set it will return 0 if that bit is not set, and non-zero if it is set, e.g.

```
  11110111
& 00001000
  --------
= 00000000

  00001111
& 00001000
  --------
= 00001000
```

Then, since C++ will convert treat any non-zero value as true when converting to a `bool` and zero as false the function works.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is also tagged C, C99 has this to say:

> 6.3.1.2 Boolean type
>
> 1 When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.